# How to split a string based on empty/blank lines?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qstring

I'm writing a c++ application (Qt Widgets) that is supposed to parse an .srt subtitle file. Each part of the file is separated by an empty line, like this:

```
1
00:00:08,000 --> 00:00:11,000
[Line]

2
00:00:56,034 --> 00:00:57,492
[Line]
[Another line]

3
00:01:13,676 --> 00:01:15,420
[Line]
```

Basically, I want to read the entire file to a `QString`, and split it by empty lines into `QString` array, each item containing one of those sections like this:

```
2
00:00:56,034 --> 00:00:57,492
[Line]
[Another line]
```

However, I cannot figure out how to do this. I tried splitting the string by `\r` and `\n`, but that split everything into separate lines, not by empty lines.

This is the routine I had in mind to get the data from the .srt file:

- Read all of the contents of the file to a `QString` (named something along the lines of `content`).
- Split the `QString` by empty lines, and append to a `QStringList` (named something along the lines of `sections`).
- For each item in `sections`, split the second line by the `-->` identifier, and assign indexes *0* and *1* to `QString` variables called `startTime`, and `endTime`, respectively.
- Take the rest of the lines (everything after line 2 is the subtitle text), and append them to a `QString` called `subtitleText`.
- Add all the gathered information to an `SrtSubtitle` instance, and append it to `QList<SrtSubtitle>`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: *The class initializer looks like this: new* -- What reason do you have why you use `new` to create your object?  C++ is not Java or C#.  If `QList` works like any of the standard classes, and it is a QList of `StrSubtitleItem`, then `qList.add(StrSubtitleItem(start, end, subtitleText));` or whatever the `add` function would be called should work.

Comment: I was not aware of this. I program more in C# and Java anyway (Android & Windows development). Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New lines are usually represented as `\n`.

To split the string when there are 2 new lines without anything between them, you can use `\n\n` as delimiter.

Comment: This is not robust enough. On Windows the new lines can be delimited with "\r\n". And also the blank lines can contain whitespace characters (e.g. when user translates the texts and put some space or tabs into the empty lines by mistake). This proposed solution is so fragile I would never recommend it to be used in a production quality software.

Comment: Yes, you can go more in depth to make it more robust. But in this case, his output looks generated. Hence why this solution works when there are no whitespaces in between. You also don't want to make it too complicated where its not necessary.

Comment: Yes, but handling windows line endings "\r\n" would make sense even if it is autogenerated.

Comment: @V.K. That may depend as well on how the file is read. In Windows, there is the so-called text mode (default in streams without `std::ios::binary` flag) which replaces every `\r\n` by `\n` while reading. Nevertheless, this may strike back if Windows text files are read in Linux. Additionally, I painfully became aware of this issue when processing text in coliru (the online compiler) which was actual the source code itself typed in in the website...

Answer (score 1):

I would improve upon ziarra's answer. You certainly want the solution to be robust and work also with Windows line endings which are `"\r\n"` instead of `"\n"`. In that case ziarra's solution would not suffice.

So my proposal is to do it in two steps:

1. replace all occurrences of `"\r\n"` with `"\n"`
2. split the text by `"\n\n"` (as ziarra suggests)